# Loop Explanation in Counting Sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, loops

Could somebody please explain to me the purpose of the second loop in this implementation of counting sort?:

```
short c[RADIX_MAX] = {0};
int i;

for (i = 0; i < LEN_MAX; i++) {
    if (i == len)
        break;
    int ind = a.getElem(i); 
    c[ind]++;
}

for (i = 1; i < RADIX_MAX; i++) {
    if (i == radix)
        break;
    c[i] += c[i - 1];
}

for (i = LEN_MAX - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int j = i - LEN_MAX + len;      
    if (j < 0)
        break;
    int ind = a.getElem(j);
    short t = ind;
    ind = --c[ind];
    b.setElem(ind, t);
}
```

Comment: Try to come up with a toy example to walk through the code? That way you get better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting sort works by calculating the target index of each element to be sorted from the value of the element itself. There are three passes involved:

- In the first loop, each element is counted: for example our array has six "A"s and two "B"s, five "C"s and so on.
- In the second loop, the index where each element goes is calculated. If there are six "A"s, then the first "B" needs to go at index 6 (in 0-based indexing). What the counting sort does is a bit more complicated in order to make the code simpler and the sort stable. In the third loop it will traverse the original array in *reverse* order, so in the second loop it calculates the index not of the *first* instance of a given value, but of the *last*. In our example above, the last "A" needs to appear at index 5, but the last "B" needs to go at index 6 ("A"s) + 2 ("B"s) - 1 (zero based) = index 7.  So for each value it calculates the ending index of that value. It walks the count array forward, adding the previosely calculated count to the current count. So in our count array, the value for "A" remains at 6 (no previous element), the value for "B" is 6+2=8 (six "A" + two "B"s), the value for C is now 6+2+5=13 (six "A"s + two "B"s + five "C"s), and so on
- In the last loop, the values are inserted in their position, decrementing the indexes as we go along. So the last of the "B"s is inserted at index 7, the one before that at index 6, and so on. This preserves the original order of equal elements, making the sort *stable* which is essential for Radix sort.

Answer (score 1):

For each digit we count index where it starts from in sorted array. 
Example:
`array: 0 0 0 0 2 2 3 3 3 9 9`

`index: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Then c[0] = 0, c[1] = 4, c[2] = 4, c [3] = 6, c[4] = 9, ... c[9] = 9.

Index in sorted array where digit appears depends on index of previous digit and number of previous digit. Second loop counts this.